# Convert Column with with dates to Eastern Time and Account for DST

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a column with datetime objects that currently does not account for DST and is also in central time. Is there an easy way to convert the entire column to eastern and adjust for DST?

Example:

| I.D. | TSTART |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5/23/2021 5:00:00 PM |
| 2 | 4/6/2021 7:00:00 PM |
| 3 | 5/23/2021 3:00:00 PM |
| 4 | 12/23/2021 3:00:00 PM |
| 5 | 2/23/2021 1:00:00 PM |

Comment: To clarify: the date/time data you have has a fixed UTC offset, i.e. that of US/Central (6h behind UTC)?

Comment: @MrFruppes - Yes, correct. No DST consideration at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert to datetime datatype, localize to a fixed UTC offset (-6 hours in that case), and then convert to any other time zone.

**EX:**

set a fixed UTC offset first:

```
from datetime import timedelta, timezone
CST = timezone(timedelta(hours=-6))

df['TSTART'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TSTART']).dt.tz_localize(CST)

df['TSTART']
0   2021-05-23 17:00:00-06:00
1   2021-04-06 19:00:00-06:00
2   2021-05-23 15:00:00-06:00
3   2021-12-23 15:00:00-06:00
4   2021-02-23 13:00:00-06:00
Name: TSTART, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC-06:00]
```

now you can convert easily:

```
df['TSTART_tz'] = df['TSTART'].dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')

df['TSTART_tz']
0   2021-05-23 19:00:00-04:00
1   2021-04-06 21:00:00-04:00
2   2021-05-23 17:00:00-04:00
3   2021-12-23 16:00:00-05:00
4   2021-02-23 14:00:00-05:00
Name: TSTART_tz, dtype: datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.